# Como criar botões para aumentar/diminuir fonte?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, acessibilidade

Gostaria de implementar funções de acessibilidade no site da empresa que trabalho.

Consegui implementar o botão de contraste, porém estou tendo dificuldade em fazer o aumento/decremento e tamanho padrão da fonte.

Fazendo testes em projetos novos os scripts que criei/achei na internet funcionam, mas no site não, não sei se algo está interferindo, mas não funciona. Alguém pode me ajudar?

Abaixo o código que fiz pro contraste:

```
if (localStorage.getItem('accessibility') == 'on') {
  $("body").addClass("accessibility");
}
$(".contrasteOn").click(function() {
  localStorage.setItem('accessibility', 'on');
  $("body").addClass("accessibility");
});
$(".contrasteOff").click(function() {
  localStorage.setItem('accessibility', null); 
  $("body").removeClass("accessibility");
});
```

Para alterar as cores eu inclui no CSS todas as classes que eu queria mudar com o `.accessibility` antes.

Comment: Poste aqui o código que você fez para o contraste.

Comment: if (localStorage.getItem('accessibility') == 'on') {
        $("body").addClass("accessibility");
    }
    
    $(".contrasteOn").click(function() {
        localStorage.setItem('accessibility', 'on');
        $("body").addClass("accessibility");
    });
    
    $(".contrasteOff").click(function() {
        localStorage.setItem('accessibility', null);
        $("body").removeClass("accessibility");
    });

Para alterar as cores eu inclui no css todas as classes q eu queria mudar com o .accessibility antes

Comment: Para adicionar código ou adicionar informações a sua pergunta clique em [Editar](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/102712/edit) para editar sua pergunta, ;)

Comment: Poessoal como coloco este script do no site

Answer (score 9):

Estou me valendo da resposta anterior e adaptando-a a um script que funciona para todas as tags, inclusive as que pertence a um *parent* dentro do próprio elemento.

No caso, deve-se apenas escolher um elemento pai onde as alterações no tamanho da font devem acontecer, no meu exemplo é o `#content`:

```js
var $btnAumentar = $("#btnAumentar");
var $btnDiminuir = $("#btnDiminuir");
var $elemento = $("body #content").find("*"); //encontra todos os elementos dentro do #content
var fonts = [];

function obterTamanhoFonte() {
  for (var i = 0; i < $elemento.length; i++) {
    fonts.push(parseFloat($elemento.eq(i).css('font-size')));
  }
}
obterTamanhoFonte();
$btnAumentar.on('click', function() {
  for (var i = 0; i < $elemento.length; i++) {
    ++fonts[i];
    $elemento.eq(i).css('font-size', fonts[i]);
  }
});

$btnDiminuir.on('click', function() {
  for (var i = 0; i < $elemento.length; i++) {
    --fonts[i];
    $elemento.eq(i).css('font-size', fonts[i]);
  }
});
```

```css
h3{
  font-size: 24pt;
}
p{
  font-size: 14pt;
}
a{
  font-size: 10pt;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src=""></script>

<button type="button" id="btnAumentar">Aumentar fonte</button>
<button type="button" id="btnDiminuir">Diminuir fonte</button>

<div id="content">
  <h3>Neque porro quisquam</h3>
  <p>Neque porro quisquam est qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit...
    <a>Neque porro quisquam est qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit...</a>
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Ótima solução! +1

Comment: Muito bom, me ajudou!

Answer (score 3):

Como vi que está utilizando jQuery em seu código fiz um exemplo:

Você pode obter o tamanho da fonte do elemento que desejar, classe ou o que for, e no clique do botão aumentar ou diminuir a fonte.

```js
var $btnAumentar = $("#btnAumentar");
var $btnDiminuir = $("#btnDiminuir");
var $elemento = $("body p");

function obterTamnhoFonte() {
  return parseFloat($elemento.css('font-size'));
}

$btnAumentar.on('click', function() {
  $elemento.css('font-size', obterTamnhoFonte() + 1);
});

$btnDiminuir.on('click', function() {
  $elemento.css('font-size', obterTamnhoFonte() - 1);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button type="button" id="btnAumentar">Aumentar fonte</button>
<button type="button" id="btnDiminuir">Diminuir fonte</button>
<p>Neque porro quisquam est qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit...</p>
```

Comment: entao mas e para pegar todas as fontes ?

eu vou ter q fzr isso para todas as tags da minha pagina ?

Comment: @HérculesMacedo no caso este código vai mudar a fonte de todas as tags `<p>`. Para mudar também das tags `<blockquote>` por exemplo, pode usar assim: `var $elemento = $("body p, blockquote");`. Mas testando com `h1` e `h2` por exemplo não deu certo... ele acaba transformando a fonte do `h1` igual a do `p`. Cheguei até a setar um valor pro font-size do `h1` por CSS, mas não resolveu. Sabe porque Pedro? Tem como alterar também dos `h's` com este script? +1

Comment: @Pedro , peço licença para me valer da sua resposta e adaptá-la a um script que funciona para todas as tags.

Comment: @HérculesMacedo, olhe a resposta e veja se lhe serve.

Comment: entao @SamirBraga, eu testei no site e algumas tags n mudaram tbm, ai conversando com um professor de um curso de EAD consegui fazer com outro codigo q vou postar abaixo

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var section = new Array('span', 'li', 'b', 'h1', 'h2', 'h3', 'h4', 'h5', 'h6', 'p', 'table', 'div');
    section = section.join(',');

    // Reset Font Size
    var originalFontSize = $(section).css('font-size');
    $(".resetFont").click(function () {
        $(section).css('font-size', originalFontSize);
    });

    // Increase Font Size
    $(".increaseFont").click(function () {
        var currentFontSize = $(section).css('font-size');
        var currentFontSizeNum = parseFloat(currentFontSize, 5);
        if (currentFontSizeNum < 20) {
            var newFontSize = currentFontSizeNum * 1.2;
            $(section).css('font-size', newFontSize);
        }
        return false;
    });

    // Decrease Font Size
    $(".decreaseFont").click(function () {
        var currentFontSize = $(section).css('font-size');
        var currentFontSizeNum = parseFloat(currentFontSize, 5);
        if (currentFontSizeNum > 10) {
            var newFontSize = currentFontSizeNum * 0.8;
            $(section).css('font-size', newFontSize);
        }
        return false;
    });
});
```

O problema dele é que o reset não está trazendo o padrão de volta pro site

ai eu pensei em usar o reset pra recarregar o arquivo CSS

Mas n sei mt bem como fzr isso, oq tentei aki n funcionou mt bem

Answer (score 0):

Eu solucionaria isso da seguinte forma.
- Javascript para adiconar uma classe na sua body/html para ser usado como seletor mestre que determina a font
- Css que controla os elementos afetados.

```
// css
body.fontSize10 {
  h1 {
    font-size: 10px;
  }
}

body.fontSize11 {
  h1 {
    font-size: 11px;
  }
}

body.fontSize12 {
  h1 {
    font-size: 12px;
  }
}

// js /jquery
$(function ($) {

  $('body').data('fontSize', 0)

  function UpdateFontSize() {
    var $body = $('body')
    var fz = $body.data('fontSize')
    var bodyClass = 'fontSize'+ fz ? fontSize.toString() : ''
    if (fz > 0){
      $body.addClass(bodyClass)
    }
  }

  $('#incrementFontSize').on('click', function (e) {
    var $body = $('body')
    var fz = $body.data('fontSize')
    $body.removeClass('fontSize'+fz).data('fontSize', fz + 1)
    UpdateFontSize()
    e.preventDefault()
  })

  $('#decrementFontSize').on('click', function (e) {
    $body.removeClass('fontSize'+fz).data('fontSize', fz - 1)
    UpdateFontSize()
    e.preventDefault()
  })

})()
```

desta forma, vc pode controlar mais facilmente os elementos afetados pelo incremento/decremento da fonte.

Fazer tudo isso somente com js pode ser muito lento, e vc pode ter a necessidade de fazer varios IFs no meio do codigo. A manutencao vai ser muito mais chata, fora qua quando adicionar um novo elemento no html, vc vai ter que alterar seu javascript.

Por meio do css vc pode controlar todos os elementos somente com o css.

Answer (score -1):

Eu tive que fazer isso uma vez num projeto, veja se serve para você:

```
function strReplace(haystack, needle, replacement) {
    var temp = haystack.split(needle);
    return temp.join(replacement);
}

 $(document).ready(function(){

    var div = '#content',
        contador = 0,
        obj_tratados = [
                        div,
                        div + ' p',
                        div + ' h1'
                       ],
        reset_fonte = [],
        reset_linha = [];

    setDefaultZoom(obj_tratados, reset_fonte, reset_linha, contador);

    $('#a_mais,#a_menos,#a_reset').on('click', function() {
       var id = $(this).attr('id');
        var min = 9;
        var max = 28;

        for (var i in obj_tratados) {

            var tratados = $(obj_tratados[i]);
            var tamanho_fonte = strReplace(tratados.css('fontSize'), 'px', '');
            var tamanho_entrelinha = strReplace(tratados.css('lineHeight'), 'px', '');

            switch (id) {
                case 'a_mais':
                    if (tamanho_fonte <= max) {
                        tamanho_fonte++;
                         // tamanho entrelinha aumento
                         tamanho_entrelinha = (tamanho_fonte * 1.8);
                         tamanho_entrelinha++;
                        contador++;

                    }
                    break;
                case 'a_menos':
                    if (tamanho_fonte >= min) {
                        tamanho_fonte--;
                       // tamanho entrelinha redução;
                        var val = tamanho_entrelinha - (tamanho_entrelinha * 3 / 100);
                       // tamanho_entrelinha = arredondarValor(val);
                       tamanho_entrelinha = (tamanho_fonte * 1.8);
                        tamanho_entrelinha--;
                        contador++;

                    }
                    break;
                case 'a_reset':
                default:
                    // resetar 
                    tamanho_fonte = reset_fonte[i];
                    tamanho_entrelinha = reset_linha[i];
                    break;
            }
            tratados.css({'fontSize': tamanho_fonte + 'px', 'lineHeight': tamanho_entrelinha + 'px'});
        }
       //cancel a click event
        return false;
    });

    function setDefaultZoom(obj_tratados, reset_fonte, reset_linha, contador) {
        for (var i in obj_tratados) {

            var tratados = $(obj_tratados[i]);
            if (contador == 0) {
                reset_fonte[i] = strReplace(tratados.css('fontSize'), 'px', '');
                reset_linha[i] = strReplace(tratados.css('lineHeight'), 'px', '');
            }
        }
    }
});
```

HTML:

```
<span id="controle_zoom">
   <a href="javascript:void(0);" id="a_reset">A</a> | <a href="javascript:void(0);" id="a_mais">A+</a> | <a href="javascript:void(0);" id="a_menos">A-</a>
</span>

<div id="content">
  <h1>Título</h1>
    <p>O texto vem aqui</p>
</div>
```