# Alterar tamanho da fonte JavaScript/HTML/Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

criei esta aplicação em HTML/JavaScript/Jquery ...
Gostaria de saber como eu coloco um botão para aumentar tamanho da fonte dentro do textarea. Alguem tem uma ideia?

```html
<html>

<meta charset="UTF-8"> <!-- add special characters -->

 <head>

  <title>Página</title> <!-- Add page title -->

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script> <!-- add Jquery CDN -->

  <link href src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen"> <!-- add bootstrap css CDN --> 

 </head>


 <body class="corpo">

  <h1><center>Página Monstra</center></h1> <!--  -->
   <hr/>

 
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script> <!-- add Bootstrap CDN -->

  <script
    src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.js"
     integrity="sha256-0YPKAwZP7Mp3ALMRVB2i8GXeEndvCq3eSl/WsAl1Ryk="
      crossorigin="anonymous"></script> <!-- library draggable -->

  <link href="design.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen"> <!-- Add css in html -->



  <script type="text/javascript"> // all javascript/jquery code start here


  function mover(){
  $('.mover').draggable(); // add draggable library

  };

   function add_field() 
     {
      
          // ------------------------------------------------------
          var form = document.getElementsByTagName('form')[0],
         input = document.createElement('textarea');
            input.setAttribute('id',count.toString());
         input.setAttribute('type', 'textarea');
         input.setAttribute('name', 'item');
            form.appendChild(input);

            input = document.createElement('button');
         input.setAttribute('type', 'button');
         input.setAttribute('onclick',"document.getElementById(" + count + ").style = 'background-color:blue;';");
         input.setAttribute('name', 'item');
         input.setAttribute('class', 'btnalterar');
         form.appendChild(input);


         input = document.createElement('button');
         input.setAttribute('type', 'button');
         input.setAttribute('onclick',"document.getElementById(" + count + ").style = 'background-color:white;';");
         input.setAttribute('name', 'item');
         input.setAttribute('class', 'btnalterar');
         form.appendChild(input);

        };


         function info(){
          alert("ATÉ 10 CAIXAS DE TEXTO");

         };
          
          var count = 0;
          
         
           function contador() 
     {

          count++;
          console.log(count); // show count in console

          if(count >= 10){
           $( ".button" ).prop( "disabled", true ); // disable button

          }
        };

 
  </script>


   <form name="input" method="get">
       <div class="ui-input-text">      
           <div data-role="navbar">
                 <button type="button" class="button" onclick="add_field(); contador(); mover();">ADICIONAR CAIXAS DE TEXTO</button> <!-- Create add button -->
           <button onclick="info();">i</button><br><br>
           </div>
       </div>
   </form>


   <!-- SALVAR -->


   <form name="input" method="get">
       <div class="ui-input-text">      
           <div data-role="navbar">
                 <button type="button" class="btnsave">SALVAR</button><br><br> <!-- Create save button -->
           </div>
       </div>
   </form>


   <div class="mover">
   <br>
    <button onclick="mover();">Click</button>
   </div>
   
 </body>

</html>
```

Comment: pode usar html dentro da caixa de texto?

Answer (score 0):

Aqui está um pequeno exemplo de como fazer isso:

Os passos são os seguintes:

Use os métodos GetElement para mirar no textarea que desejar, diga pro Javascript que você quer alterar um estilo e que esse estilo é o fontSize e atribua um valor para ele.

Nesse exemplo, ao clicar no Botão, ele vai alterar a fonte do Textarea.

Espero que entenda.

```html
<html>
 <head>
 </head>
 <body>
 <textarea id="oi" style=""></textarea>
  <button type="button" id="botao" onclick="aumentar()">Click Me!</button> 
 </body>
 <script>
 function aumentar(){
  document.getElementById("oi").style.fontSize="40px";
 }
 </script> 
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Adaptado da resposta de [Pedro Camara Junior](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/102712/como-criar-bot%C3%B5es-para-aumentar-diminuir-fonte/102724#102724)

```js
var $btnAumentar = $("#btnAumentar");
var $elemento = $("body .minhaTextarea");

function obterTamnhoFonte() {
  return parseFloat($elemento.css('font-size'));
}

$btnAumentar.on('click', function() {
  $elemento.css('font-size', obterTamnhoFonte() + 1);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button type="button" id="btnAumentar">Aumentar fonte</button>
<textarea rows="3" cols="30" class="minhaTextarea">O Alexandre quer alterar tamanho da fonte JavaScript/HTML/Jquery
</textarea>
```