# Tratar campos em branco em cálculo

Tags: javascript

Estou a fazer um simulador no meu site com JavaScript, está tudo a funcionar certo menos uma coisa.

Quando eu deixo os campos em branco ele não faz o cálculo, obrigando me a preencher, nem que seja com `0` para que ele faça o cálculo.

Aqui deixo o código que tenho até agora e uma imagem do problema:

```js
            function calculate()
            {
                var field1=document.getElementById("num1").value;
                var field2=document.getElementById("num2").value;
                var field3=document.getElementById("num3").value;
                var field4=document.getElementById("num4").value;
                var field5=document.getElementById("num5").value;
                var field6=document.getElementById("num6").value;
                var field7=document.getElementById("num7").value;
                var field8=document.getElementById("num8").value;
                var field9=document.getElementById("num9").value;
                var field10=document.getElementById("num10").value;
                var field11=document.getElementById("num11").value;
                var field12=document.getElementById("num12").value;
                var field13=document.getElementById("num13").value;
                var field14=document.getElementById("num14").value;
                var field15=document.getElementById("num15").value;
                var field16=document.getElementById("num16").value;
                
                var result=(parseFloat(field1)*0+parseFloat(field2)*1.10+parseFloat(field3)*2.20+parseFloat(field4)*1.70+parseFloat(field5)*2+parseFloat(field6)*2.50+parseFloat(field7)*2.10+parseFloat(field8)*2.20+parseFloat(field9)*2.30+parseFloat(field10)*1+parseFloat(field11)*6.70+parseFloat(field12)*1.70+parseFloat(field13)*3.80+parseFloat(field14)*1.70+parseFloat(field15)*1.50)*parseFloat(field16);
                var arredondado = parseFloat(result.toFixed(2));
                if(!isNaN(result))
                {
                    document.getElementById("answer").innerHTML="O valor é €" +arredondado;
                    
                }
                
                
            }
```

```html
Pessoas<br>
            Até 5 anos.............<input type="text" id="num1">
            <br>
            De 5 a 10 anos......<input type="text" id="num2">
            <br>
            Mais de 10 anos..<input type="text" id="num3">
            <br>
            Tendas<br>
            Até 4 metros........<input type="text" id="num4">
            <br>
            De 5 a 12 metros..<input type="text" id="num5">
            <br>
            De 13 a 20 metros<input type="text" id="num6">
            <br>
            Caravana<br>
            Até 4 metros........<input type="text" id="num7">
            <br>
            De 5 a 6 metros....<input type="text" id="num8">
            <br>
            Mais de 6 metros<input type="text" id="num9">
            <br>
            Viaturas
            <br>
            Reboque................<input type="text" id="num10">
            <br>
            Autocarro.............<input type="text" id="num11">
            <br>
            Automóvel...........<input type="text" id="num12">
            <br>
            Autocaravana.....<input type="text" id="num13">
            <br>
            Motocicletas........<input type="text" id="num14">
            <br>
            Outras<br>
            Electricidade.......<input type="text" id="num15">
            <br>
            <br>
            Dias.........................<input type="text" id="num16">
            <br>
            <br>
            <button onclick="calculate()">Calcular</button>
```

[image: Texto]

Comment: Faz um if para se o campo for vazio, colocar que seu valor é zero

Comment: tentei, mas sempre que deixo um campo em branco continua não dando output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gostaria de sugerir uma outra solução, pois não me parece que você está fazendo da melhor maneira (*entenda como crítica construtiva*).

Se a ideia é ter vários números, cada um vindo de um `input`, e você quer iterar por todos eles, uma opção seria usar [seletores](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors), juntamente com [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll), para facilitar sua vida.

Por exemplo, se a ideia é pegar todos os campos `input type="text"`, uma alternativa seria usar `document.querySelectorAll('input[type="text"]')`. Com isso, você terá uma lista com todos os campos, bastando percorrê-los com um *loop* simples. Ou ainda, se quiser apenas os campos cujo atributo `id` comece com "num", poderia fazer `document.querySelectorAll('input[id^="num"]')`, por exemplo.

Ou então você seta os campos que interessam com uma classe. Ex:

```html
<input type="text" id="num1" class="quantidade-item">
```

E aí você busca todos os elementos que possuem esta classe, com `document.querySelectorAll('input.quantidade-item')`.

---

Como cada um dos campos possui um fator multiplicativo, você pode usar um [*dataset*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLOrForeignElement/dataset) para que cada campo tenha o valor correspondente. Ex:

```html
<input type="text" id="num2" class="quantidade-item" data-multiplicador="1.1">
```

Assim, cada campo tem a informação do valor pelo qual será multiplicado (como veremos a seguir, o uso do *dataset*, juntamente com os *selectors*, facilitará muito o algoritmo e simplificará o código).

---

Agora vamos ao cálculo em si. Você está multiplicando cada campo por um número e somando os resultados, e quer que o valor seja zero caso o campo esteja vazio.

Vamos supor que temos apenas 3 campos, então a conta seria:

```
field1 * valor1 + field2 * valor2 + field3 * valor3
```

Agora vamos pensar: o que acontece se `field1` for zero? Nesse caso, `field1 * valor1` será zero e não mudará em nada o resultado da soma. Então para que transformar o campo em zero, sendo que isso não irá alterar o resultado? Se o campo estiver vazio, **simplesmente não inclua ele na soma**.

Sei que você pensou que "*se for vazio, vira zero*" podia ser uma boa solução, mas se formos analisar bem, basta ignorar os campos vazios, já que o valor zero não fará diferença no resultado.

> *Aliás, no seu código você está fazendo `parseFloat(field1)*0`, ou seja, está multiplicando o primeiro `input` por zero, **o que também não altera a soma**. Isso quer dizer que o valor de `field1` não fará a menor diferença no resultado final, então nem sei para que esse campo existe (a menos que ele seja usado em outros lugares, claro, mas mesmo assim incluí-lo nesse cálculo específico é totalmente desnecessário - e só o mantive no exemplo abaixo para você ver como ficaria).*

No exemplo abaixo também mudei o `id` do último `input` para "dias" (poderia ter mudado o dos outros também, para que tenham nomes mais significativos, mas deixei como o original), e este `input id="dias"` é o único que não tem a `class="quantidade-item"`, pois ele não tem fator multiplicador e não deve ser incluso no *loop* principal (se bem que no exemplo abaixo eu também poderia fazer `document.querySelectorAll('input[data-multiplicador]')` para pegar todos os campos menos esse, pois é o único que não tem valor no `dataset`).

Também uso um método matemático para deixar o número com apenas 2 casas decimais (pois [`toFixed`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed) pode arredondar o valor, dependendo do caso) - mas é só para dizer que há outra maneira, pois você vê qual se encaixa melhor para o seu caso (por exemplo, se o resultado for `1.427`, usar `toFixed(2)` arredonda para `1.43`, já usando o que eu fiz, ele não arredonda e só mantém as casas decimais, resultando em `1.42`).

O código abaixo também mostra uma mensagem se não for digitado um número no campo. E como o resultado final se trata de um valor monetário, incluí uma opção com `toLocaleString`, para mostrar como formatar adequadamente para o seu caso (mas não deixe de ver mais opções na [documentação](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toLocaleString)):

```js
function arredonda(valor, casas) {
    let fator = Math.pow(10, casas);
    return Math.floor(valor * fator) / fator;
}

function calculate() {
    let dias = parseFloat(document.querySelector('input#dias').value);
    if (isNaN(dias)) {
        alert('quantidade de dias deve ser um número');
    } else {
        let soma = 0;
        for (const input of document.querySelectorAll('input.quantidade-item')) {
            if (input.value !== '') { // só prossigo se o campo não for vazio
                let valor = parseFloat(input.value);
                if (isNaN(valor)) {
                    alert(`Campo ${input.id} não é um número`);
                    return; // não é número, interrompe o cálculo (não tem porque prosseguir)
                } else {
                    // multiplica o valor do campo pelo multiplicador que está no dataset e atualiza a soma
                    soma += valor * parseFloat(input.dataset.multiplicador);
                }
            }
        }
        // multiplica a soma pela quantidade de dias e arredonda para 2 casas decimais
        document.querySelector('p#resultado').textContent = 'O valor é ' + arredonda(soma * dias, 2);
        // só incluí um alert para mostrar que o valor foi calculado corretamente
        // e também para mostrar a opção com toLocaleString
        alert('O valor é ' + arredonda(soma * dias, 2).toLocaleString('en', {style: 'currency', currency: 'EUR'}));
    }
}
```

```html
Pessoas<br>
Até 5 anos.............<input type="text" id="num1" class="quantidade-item" data-multiplicador="0">
<br>
De 5 a 10 anos......<input type="text" id="num2" class="quantidade-item" data-multiplicador="1.1">
<br>
Mais de 10 anos..<input type="text" id="num3" class="quantidade-item" data-multiplicador="2.2">
<br>
Tendas<br>
Até 4 metros........<input type="text" id="num4" class="quantidade-item" data-multiplicador="1.7">
<br>
De 5 a 12 metros..<input type="text" id="num5" class="quantidade-item" data-multiplicador="2">
<br>
De 13 a 20 metros<input type="text" id="num6" class="quantidade-item" data-multiplicador="2.5">
<br>
Caravana<br>
Até 4 metros........<input type="text" id="num7" class="quantidade-item" data-multiplicador="2.1">
<br>
De 5 a 6 metros....<input type="text" id="num8" class="quantidade-item" data-multiplicador="2.2">
<br>
Mais de 6 metros<input type="text" id="num9" class="quantidade-item" data-multiplicador="2.3">
<br>
Viaturas
<br>
Reboque................<input type="text" id="num10" class="quantidade-item" data-multiplicador="1">
<br>
Autocarro.............<input type="text" id="num11" class="quantidade-item" data-multiplicador="6.7">
<br>
Automóvel...........<input type="text" id="num12" class="quantidade-item" data-multiplicador="1.7">
<br>
Autocaravana.....<input type="text" id="num13" class="quantidade-item" data-multiplicador="3.8">
<br>
Motocicletas........<input type="text" id="num14" class="quantidade-item" data-multiplicador="1.7">
<br>
Outras<br>
Electricidade.......<input type="text" id="num15" class="quantidade-item" data-multiplicador="1.5">
<br>
<br>
Dias.........................<input type="text" id="dias">
<br>
<br>
<button onclick="calculate()">Calcular</button>
<p id="resultado"></p>
```

Um detalhe é que o atributo `data-multiplicador` estará disponível no JavaScript na propriedade `dataset.multiplicador` (não sei porque não deram o mesmo nome em ambos, mas é assim que funciona).

Vale lembrar também que não faz sentido `dias` ser zero caso o campo seja vazio, pois você multiplica a soma por `dias`, então se `dias` for zero, o resultado final será zero (ou seja, se `dias` estiver vazio ou tiver qualquer outro valor inválido, não faz sentido sequer começar o cálculo, por isso o primeiro `if` para verificar se o campo `dias` é um número).

---

Sei que do seu jeito "funciona", mas só quis mostrar que há outras maneiras - na minha opinião, melhores - de atacar esse problema :-)

Por exemplo, se tiver que adicionar ou remover um campo, ou mudar o fator multiplicador, basta alterar o HTML, pois o código JavaScript continuará o mesmo (no seu código, além de mudar o HTML, você teria que adicionar/remover o campo na função JavaScript e alterar o multiplicador). Sem contar que o código acima ficou bem mais simples e fácil de entender (e modificar, se for o caso).

Comment: tenho só uma questão, quando se imprime o resultado final no alerta aparece com 2 casas decimais, mas em baixo aparece apenas com 1, estive a ver e o código é o mesmo, qual poderá ser o problema? e também como é que faria para aumentar o tamanho de letra da resposta?

Comment: @DavidPeixoto Tem diferença. No `alert` eu uso `toLocaleString`, que serve justamente para formatar o valor

Comment: eu tentei com o fontsize para alterar mas não consegui, tem como deixar uma sample de como ficaria?

Comment: @DavidPeixoto No exemplo acima é só fazer no final `document.querySelector('p#resultado').textContent = 'O valor é ' + arredonda(soma * dias, 2).toLocaleString('en', {style: 'currency', currency: 'EUR'});` - o fontsize só muda o tamanho da fonte, quem controla o formato e casas decimais é o `toLocaleString`

Comment: eu das casas decimais consegui, não consegui foi a parte de aumentar o tamanho da fonte

Comment: @DavidPeixoto https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/240139/112052

Comment: estava-me a faltar fechar uma parte, por isso não estava a funcionar, já deu, agradecido mais uma vez.

Comment: Bela resposta, parabéns! aprendi mais um pouco. Agora me diga, esse treco id^= acho que tem um nome, você sabe qual é?

Comment: @LeoCaracciolo https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors

Answer (score 1):

Use o [**operador lógico OR**](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operadores_Logicos#OR_L%C3%B3gico_())  `||` - é um operador lógico que retorna o seu operando do lado direito quando o seu operador do lado esquerdo é null ou undefined.

```
    var field1 = document.getElementById("num1").value || 0;
```

```js
    function calculate()
        {
         var field1=document.getElementById("num1").value || 0;
         var field2=document.getElementById("num2").value || 0;
         var field3=document.getElementById("num3").value || 0;
         var field4=document.getElementById("num4").value || 0;
         var field5=document.getElementById("num5").value || 0;
         var field6=document.getElementById("num6").value || 0;
         var field7=document.getElementById("num7").value || 0;
         var field8=document.getElementById("num8").value || 0;
         var field9=document.getElementById("num9").value || 0;
         var field10=document.getElementById("num10").value || 0;
         var field11=document.getElementById("num11").value || 0;
         var field12=document.getElementById("num12").value || 0;
         var field13=document.getElementById("num13").value || 0;
         var field14=document.getElementById("num14").value || 0;
         var field15=document.getElementById("num15").value || 0;
         var field16=document.getElementById("num16").value || 0;
                     
          var result=(parseFloat(field1)*0+parseFloat(field2)*1.10+parseFloat(field3)*2.20+parseFloat(field4)*1.70+parseFloat(field5)*2+parseFloat(field6)*2.50+parseFloat(field7)*2.10+parseFloat(field8)*2.20+parseFloat(field9)*2.30+parseFloat(field10)*1+parseFloat(field11)*6.70+parseFloat(field12)*1.70+parseFloat(field13)*3.80+parseFloat(field14)*1.70+parseFloat(field15)*1.50)*parseFloat(field16);

         var arredondado = parseFloat(result.toFixed(2));
         if(!isNaN(result))
           {
              //document.getElementById("answer").innerHTML="O valor é €" +arredondado;
        
             console.log(arredondado)
                        
           }
                               
        }
```

```html
  Pessoas<br>
      Até 5 anos.............<input type="text" id="num1">
      <br>
      De 5 a 10 anos......<input type="text" id="num2">
      <br>
      Mais de 10 anos..<input type="text" id="num3">
      <br>
      Tendas<br>
      Até 4 metros........<input type="text" id="num4">
      <br>
      De 5 a 12 metros..<input type="text" id="num5">
      <br>
      De 13 a 20 metros<input type="text" id="num6">
      <br>
      Caravana<br>
      Até 4 metros........<input type="text" id="num7">
      <br>
      De 5 a 6 metros....<input type="text" id="num8">
      <br>
      Mais de 6 metros<input type="text" id="num9">
      <br>
      Viaturas
      <br>
      Reboque................<input type="text" id="num10">
      <br>
      Autocarro.............<input type="text" id="num11">
      <br>
      Automóvel...........<input type="text" id="num12">
      <br>
      Autocaravana.....<input type="text" id="num13">
      <br>
      Motocicletas........<input type="text" id="num14">
      <br>
      Outras<br>
      Electricidade.......<input type="text" id="num15">
      <br>
      <br>
      Dias.........................<input type="text" id="num16">
      <br>
      <br>
      <button onclick="calculate()">Calcular</button>
```

**Para fazer o teste em Executar tem que digitar obrigatoriamente pelo menos um input a partir do segundo e também obrigatório o numero de dias.** Não vou fazer essa validação pois não é o foco da pergunta.

Comment: obrigado, fiz de forma diferente, alterei o type para number e fiz uma condição, se o valor fosse igual a 0 para o campo ser igual a 0 e deu também.

Comment: corrigi pela sua forma, fica muito melhor, obrigado

Comment: está, obrigado mais uma vez

Answer (score -2):

Basta mudar o input de text para number e inicializar um valor padrão como por exemplo 0

```
<input type="number" value="0" />
```

ou então usar o operador '??' exemplo:

```
var field1 = document.getElementById("num1").value ?? 0;
```

segue referência: https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/operador_de_coalescencia_nula

Comment: tentei ambas e não consegui, mas obrigado

Comment: realmente não iria funcionar somente com a adição do operador que indiquei, para funcionar você precisaria passar todos os inputs pra number igual eu comentei (isso evitaria que fosse digitado letras por exemplo) e atribuir um valor inicial para cada um dos inputs com a tag value="0" por exemplo, acredito que assim funcionaria o operador '??' pois ele valida null e undefined e deixando como texto sem inicializar o campo o document.getElementById("num1").value vem como string vazia.

Answer (score -3):

Suas variáveis ficam  indefinidas quando não recebem valor pós você já criou elas recebendo um valor da inputs onde ela pode ser qualquer coisa pós você criou como text.
Para resolver isso tente isso passar elas fora da função e atrelando o zero a elas.

```
var field1 = 0;
```

E dentro da função chame :

```
field1=document.getElementById("num1").value;
```

Faça o mesmo para todas e passe suas input para tipo number para evitar que o usuário coloque letras e gere um erro na conta.

Comment: testou isso? a variável fiedl1 vai ter seu conteúdo sobrescrito na mesma, faça um teste e veja se essa solução funciona

Comment: testei e não deu nada, não deu output nenhum