# Alterar tamanho da font dinamicamente javascript

Tags: javascript

Como aumentar e diminuir a font a cada clique? Eu estava procurando maneiras de fazer isso dinamicamente, porém só achei um exemplo em jQuery [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/102712/como-criar-bot%C3%B5es-para-aumentar-diminuir-fonte), mas meu projeto não usa jQuery, como posso fazer isso usando javascript puro?

**Meu código básico porém estático:**

```js
function escala(size) {
  var text = document.querySelector('p');
  text.style.fontSize = size + 'px';
}
```

```html
<button onclick="escala(10)">-</button><button onclick="escala(20)">+</button>
<p>FONT</p>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode obter o valor do tamanho de fonte por meio da função [`window#getComputedStyle`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle) e [`CSSStyleDeclaration#getPropertyValue()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleDeclaration/getPropertyValue), e então basta fazer o tratamento conforme a sua necessidade. Em um caso que seja aumentar/diminuir `1px`, pode ser feito desta forma:

```js
let increase = document.getElementById('increase');
let decrease = document.getElementById('decrease');
let main = document.querySelector('main');

let getfontsize = (el) => {
  let size = window.getComputedStyle(el, null)
                   .getPropertyValue('font-size');
  return parseFloat(size);
}

increase.addEventListener('click', () => {
  main.style.fontSize = (getfontsize(main) + 1) + 'px';
})

decrease.addEventListener('click', () => {
  main.style.fontSize = (getfontsize(main) - 1) + 'px';
})
```

```css
main {
  font-size: 20px
}
```

```html
<button id='increase'>+</button>
<button id='decrease'>-</button>

<main>
  Mussum Ipsum, cacilds vidis litro abertis. Posuere libero varius. Nullam a nisl ut ante blandit hendrerit. Aenean sit amet nisi. Quem manda na minha terra sou euzis! Sapien in monti palavris qui num significa nadis i pareci latim. Si num tem leite então bota uma pinga aí cumpadi! 
</main>
```